# How to implement a github C++ library?

Tags: c++, github, linker, shared-libraries

I am trying to use [G+smo](https://github.com/filiatra/gismo) library from github. I download, unzip it and make. Then I could run all examples in the package. But there is no tutorial that guide me to build my own cpp file. For example I tried to build the simplest code from the tutorial:

```
# include <gismo.h>
using namespace gismo;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gsInfo <<  "Hello G+Smo.\n";
    real_t a = 2.0; // a real number, ie. double
    index_t b = 3; // an integer, ie. int
    GISMO_ASSERT( a*b == 6, "This is an error, 2*3 should be 6.");
    return 0;
}
```

And linked the lib file by -lgismo, but it says 'gismo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated'. I know it my be the fact that I am not familiar with c++. Can you guys give me some suggestion about it? Or, if it is overly obvious, can you just suggest me some book to read?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error 'gismo.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.' suggests that you didn't set the path where the compiler should look for the library headers. Try adding `-I/path/to/gismo/headers` to the compiler flags, e.g. on my system `make install` by default installed it to `/usr/local/include/gismo` so I have to add `-I/usr/local/include/gismo`.

By the way, there is a "tutorial": The `README.txt` in the `deploy` folder.